# Problem with converting \frac into mathematica output

Tags: latex

Please help me with the following problem:

```
TeXForm[2/3]
```

The Answer is correct:

```
"\frac{2}{3}"
```

I don't understand why Mathematica gives me a wrong inverse:

```
ToExpression["\frac{2}{3}", TeXForm]
```

The Answer is:

```
23 a c r
```

Comment: You should escape "\" by second "\": `ToExpression["\\frac{2}{3}", TeXForm]`

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it works fine :)

Comment: I can't find that it is duplicate, so I post it as an answer to avoid unanswered questions.

Answer (score 1):

You should escape "\" by second "\"

```
ToExpression["\\frac{2}{3}", TeXForm]
```

To avoid this problem, produce strings explicitly. Copy-pasted text from the `TeXForm` is designed for an external TeX editor

```
ToString[2/3, TeXForm]
(* "\\frac{2}{3}" *)
```