# How to convert the $\LaTeX$ format to Mathematica input?

Tags: latex, conversion, input

How to convert the $\LaTeX$ format to Mathematica input?

For example, if I have a formula:

$$
\sum_{m_{i}=0}^M\sum_{n_{j}=0}^N  \frac{(z_{i}/2)^{m_{i}}(z_{j}/2)^{n_{j}}}{m!n!}
$$

in terms of $\LaTeX$ format:

```
  \sum_{m_{i}=0}^M\sum_{n_{j}=0}^N \frac{(z_{i}/2)^{m_{i}}(z_{j}/2)^{n_{j}}}{m!n!}
```

How would we convert it to Mathematica input?

Comment: We have the [MaTeX](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX) package that goes from Mathematica to LateX.  Maybe you can make a package to go the other way, and call it TeXmA.

Comment: Duplicates? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95435/toexpression-not-accepting-standard-tex-strings, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2794/unable-to-convert-tex-input-into-mathematica, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76069/problem-with-converting-frac-into-mathematica-output, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15884/how-to-use-latex-for-typesetting-labels-and-titles-in-mathematica

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use `ToExpression`.

```
ToExpression["string", TeXForm, HoldForm]
```

Paste your content inside quotes and click the button "yes", when the following dialog box opens, in order to escape backslashes and use them verbatim

[image]

In your example, Mathematica 12.1 produces the following output

[image]

Comment: It works, but strangely \sum becomes \\sum when I past into the "string"...?

Comment: That's because the backslah of the TeX expression is not intended to be interpreted as  _Mathematica code_, so it must be "escaped". The way to do this is to precede it by another backslash. Mathematica is aware of this and offers this transformation when you paste the string.